Билд Solar 2D (Corona SDK, )
Я пытаюсь скомпилировать программу на Lua (Corona SDK) но у меня ошибка
Your project path contains non-ASCII characters (У меня имя пользователя на русском)
Просьба:
При ответе на вопрос, пишите не просто "Поменяйте android.overridePathCheck на true", а ещё и писать где этот файл и во всех подробностях которые нужны
Полный текст ошибки:
14:48:33.145  Warning: 
14:48:33.145  The signer's certificate is self-signed.
14:48:33.145  
14:48:33.145  The timestamp will expire on 2031-11-10.
14:48:47.325  Excluding specified files from build: 
14:48:47.325     excluding: LaunchScreen.storyboardc
14:48:47.325     excluding: Icon.png
14:48:47.325     excluding: Icon-*dpi.png
14:48:47.325  Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Duser.language=en
14:48:47.325  
14:48:47.325  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
14:48:47.325  
14:48:47.325  * Where:
14:48:47.325  Build file 'C:\Users\    \AppData\Local\Temp\Corona Labs\CLtmpa12548\template\app\build.gradle.kts' line: 10
14:48:47.325  
14:48:47.325  * What went wrong:
14:48:47.325  An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']
14:48:47.325  > Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
14:48:47.325     > Your project path contains non-ASCII characters. This will most likely cause the build to fail on Windows. Please move your project to a different directory. See http://b.android.com/95744 for details. This warning can be disabled by adding the line 'android.overridePathCheck=true' to gradle.properties file in the project directory.
14:48:47.325  
14:48:47.325  * Try:
14:48:47.325  > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
14:48:47.325  > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
14:48:47.325  > Run with --scan to get full insights.
14:48:47.325  > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
14:48:47.325  
14:48:47.325  BUILD FAILED in 12s
14:48:47.517  Android build failed (1) after 14 seconds


Ну не пробовали перенести проект в другой каталог, без русских букв? Хотя у вас там временные файлы в юзерский временный каталог пишутся, это может так и не вылечиться.

Пробовал, в C:\Solar2D папка с проектами и билдом. Проблема с самим временным каталогом похоже

Попробуйте выставить переменные окружения TMP и TEMP в какой-то каталог без русских букв. Не очень хорошее решение, современным считается подход, когда TEMP лежит у пользователя, но другого решения не вижу. Сделайте C:\TEMP какой-нибудь и установите на него эти переменные. Ну или C:\Windows\Temp
